# Maintaining external links in Eleventy

Tags: eleventy

I'm using [markdown reference links](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.18/#link-reference-definitions) in my eleventy site.

Rather than repeatedly defining links on each page, I'd rather put them in one place, and just reference them in my pages.

For example `links.md` could contain:

```markdown
[github]: <https://github.com/>
[stackoverflow]: <https://stackoverflow.com/>
```

And then any page could reference these links.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to define the links in one spot and access them globally in your templates, you can create a [global data file](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-global/) in the `_data/*` directory containing link definitions and then reference them in your Markdown files. Below is an example global data file `_data/links.json`:

```json
{
    "socials": {
        "github": "<https://github.com/>",
        "stackoverflow": "<https://stackoverflow.com/>",
        "twitter": "<https://twitter.com/>",
        ...
    }
}
```

This way you can access the data in `_data/links.json` containing link definitions globally throughout your 11ty project using interpolation like `{{ foo }}`. Where if you want to use that global data in templates, you reference the name of the global data file `links` and then access object keys as necessary for example `{{ links.socials.key }}`.

Unfortunately using `[GitHub]({{ links.socials.github }})` won't work, but to avoid adding link definitions on each page you could always do something like:

```
---
title: Some title
templateEngineOverride: njk, md
---

<a href="{{ links.socials.github }}">GitHub</a>
```

Or if using Nunjucks as your templating engine, you could create variables for your social links using [`set`](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#set) and avoid defining Markdown reference links.

```
---
title: Some title
---

{% set github = links.socials.github %}

[Link to my GitHub]({{ github }})
```

Lastly, using a shortcode wouldn't be a bad idea paired with the global data.

```js
module.exports = function(eleventyConfig) {
    eleventyConfig.addShortCode("socialLink", function(linkName, url) {
        return `<a href="${url}">${linkName}</a>`;
    });
}

// Template Usage (.md or .njk etc)
{% socialLink "GitHub", links.socials.github %}

// outputs: <a href="<https://github.com>">GitHub</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @tanner-dolby. I've gone for the shortcodes solution